# Get publishing page url using CAML

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, url, client-object-model

I am retrieving pages using CAML, and doing for loop on the results like the following:

```
 function _onSucceed(){
     var html="";                   
     for(var i = 0; i <results.length; i++){
         html+= results[i].get_item("PublishingPageImage");
     }           
 }
```

But what property should I use if I want to get the URL for the web page? Also how do I get a list of properties I can use for the returned type. All I can see in the developer tool is just method definitions like `get_item` and so on, but how do I know exact properties I can use with `get_item()`?

Comment: Have you tried Url? The list of properties depends on what all you are requesting.

Comment: You can use Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see the properties returned by the query and so available in get_item().

Comment: Thanks @pholpar , do you have example on how to check these properties in fiddler? Do I just try it on get_item() without any param? Does it return all properties? Does it also return the values for these properties? Sorry I'm a bit lost.

Comment: You should simlpy submit your query with executeQueryAsync, no get_item() is required. Format the request as XML and the response as JSON in Fiddler, see the properties in the response. In case of a CAML query these properties should correspond with the field names requested in ViewFields.

Comment: Thanks pholpar, but this is exactly my problem, how do I know the properties I need? for example how did Amal know there is one called: FileRef?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the File URL using following property

```
function _onSucceed(){
     var html="";                   
     for(var i = 0; i <results.length; i++){
         html+= results[i].get_item("FileRef");
     }           
 }
```

To form the full URL you can use `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + results[i].get_item("FileRef")`

Answer (score 1):

When doing a CAML query for the page web URL I use:

```
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='WebPage' />" + "</ViewFields>";
```

as my CAMLViewFields

```
var web = ($(this).attr("ows_WebPage"));
```

gets the URL for the page.

```
$("#relatedTable").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=" + web + ">" + name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>");
```

That is how I display the data in a table.  As with regards to learning the field names, you have to go into the relevant list on SharePoint and lookup the column to find the internal property name used by SharePoint for the relevant field.

Answer (score 0):

FileRef will only return the relative url of the page item.
For retriving the full URL of the publishing page item, ask for the fileld

> EncodedAbsUrl